# How to alter a while loop to switch from the 3rd column to a new row?

Tags: php, while-loop

This is the code

```
$directory = 'games';

if ($handle = opendir($directory.'/')) {
    while ($cat = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($cat!='.'&&$cat!='..') {
            echo '<td><a href="'.$directory.'/'.$cat.'" style="text-decoration:none">'.str_replace('_', ' ', $cat).'</a></td>';
        }
    }
}
```

I need to alter the while loop to such to add `<tr>` at start of `<td>` and at the end of `</td>` every 3 repetitions!

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable with value 0 before the while loop begins, after the if statement do a mod 3 for the variable check for 0 and you can echo with the tags added.

```
if ($handle = opendir($directory.'/')) {
$temp=0;
while ($cat = readdir($handle)) {
if ($cat!='.'&&$cat!='..') {
if($temp % 3 == 0)
echo '<tr><td><a href="'.$directory.'/'.$cat.'" style="text-decoration:none">'.str_replace('_', ' ', $cat).'</a></td></tr>';
else echo '<td><a href="'.$directory.'/'.$cat.'" style="text-decoration:none">'.str_replace('_', ' ', $cat).'</a></td>';
$temp++;
}
}
}
```

Comment: It displays two column great, but the data on the second is displayed at second row

Answer (score 0):

```
$directory = 'games';
$row=0;
if ($handle = opendir($directory.'/')) {
    while ($cat = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($cat!='.'&&$cat!='..') {
            if($row==0) echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><a href="'.$directory.'/'.$cat.'" style="text-    decoration:none">'.str_replace('_', ' ', $cat).'</a></td>';
            if($row==2) {
              echo '</tr>';
              $row = -1;
            }
            $row++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, substitute single = in if conditions checking $row with ==

Answer (score 0):

You could use modulus:

```
$directory = 'games';

if ($handle = opendir($directory.'/')) {
    $i=0;
    while ($cat = readdir($handle)) {        
    if ($cat!='.'&&$cat!='..') {
        if($i==0){echo '<tr>';}//first
        if($i>0 && $i%3==0){echo '</td><tr>';}//modulus - every third
            $i++;
        echo '<td><a href="'.$directory.'/'.$cat.'" style="text-decoration:none">'.str_replace('_', ' ', $cat).'</a></td>';
        }
    }
    if($i>0){echo '</tr>';}//last
}
```

Comment: This displays 2 columns of the first row 3 on the second and one on the third

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've updated my example to change when $i is incremented.

Answer (score 0):

to meet standards and follow right practices of Mark-Up we must specify
    
and

```
<table>
```

tags should be specified before and after while loop. e.g.

```
$directory = 'games';
$row=0;
if ($handle = opendir($directory.'/')) {
    echo '<table>';    
    while ($cat = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($cat!='.'&&$cat!='..') {
            if($row==0) echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td><a href="'.$directory.'/'.$cat.'" style="text-    decoration:none">'.str_replace('_', ' ', $cat).'</a></td>';
            if($row==2) {
              echo '</tr>';
              $row = -1;
            }
            $row++;
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: ok this works meets the standards but can you explain it for me to understand it?